# ponydebugger error when installing

Tags: ios, ponydebugger

I got some error message after the command :

```
   curl -sk https://cloud.github.com/downloads/square/PonyDebugger/bootstrap-ponyd.py | \
  python - --ponyd-symlink=/usr/local/bin/ponyd ~/Library/PonyDebugger
```

this is my termial tell me,

```
Overwriting /Users/hokila/Library/PonyDebugger/lib/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt with new content
New python executable in /Users/hokila/Library/PonyDebugger/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2462, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 944, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 1045, in create_environment
  File "<stdin>", line 1361, in install_python
  File "<stdin>", line 435, in copyfile
  File "<stdin>", line 412, in copyfileordir
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 128, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/hokila/Library/PonyDebugger/.Python'
```

It seems the python version error,so I update my python to 2.7.3.
then I still got the same error.How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occured to me and I was almost desperate. I reinstalled Python 2.7.2 and it worked fine.
I tried to solve this problem manually before using the instructions in README_ponyd.rst and I was also partially successful:

> Development installation ````````````````````````
>
> If you already have PonyDebugger git repo checked out you can can set
>   up a virtualenv manually and have your ponyd installation point to
>   your existing checkout.  For demonstration we assume `$VENV` is set
>   to your intended install path and `$PONYDEBUGGER_PATH` is set to
>   your PonyDebugger git checkout::
>
> # if you don't already have virtualenv installed
>   sudo easy_install
>   virtualenv

virtualenv "$VENV"

source "$VENV/bin/activate"

pip install -e "$PONYDEBUGGER_PATH"

> # to ensure your shell knows ponyd exists   hash -r
>
> To run this ponyd you can either activate your environment by `source
>   "$VENV/bin/activate"` and `ponyd` will be added to your path.  You
>   can also just call it directly via `$VENV/bin/ponyd` without
>   activating first.

You should install [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) before. You can try combination of both steps. Hope it helps...